# Set existing index as alias to another index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using an application that creates an index per month in elasticsearch.

In a normal scenario the index and aliases should be as follow:

```
{
    "api-umbrella-logs-v1-2019-06" : {
        "aliases" : {
            "api-umbrella-logs-2019-06" : { },
            "api-umbrella-logs-write-2019-06" : { }
        }
     }
}
```

But somehow after restarting the application created two indexes instead of one and like this:

```
{
    "api-umbrella-logs-v1-2019-06" : {
        "aliases" : {
            "api-umbrella-logs-2019-06" : { }
        }
    },
    "api-umbrella-logs-write-2019-06" : {
        "aliases" : { }
    }
}
```

as queries are based on `api-umbrella-logs-2019-06` and write data is in `api-umbrella-logs-write-2019-06` all queries return no data. If I append `api-umbrella-logs-write-2019-06` to `api-umbrella-logs-v1-2019-06` as an alias I can solve the problem. so how is it possible?

Note: Assign alias `api-umbrella-logs-2019-06` to `api-umbrella-logs-write-2019-06` will not work because their structures are different.